# Routing to nested page/component with nested outlet not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

So I'm using the Ionic Tabs template( Ionic 4) and I'm really having trouble with routing.

Basically I have a `info` tab. That leads to the `InfoPage`. In this page I  have a list of items and  when I click on an item, I want to navigate one page deeper into the `item-info` page, using the info outlet.

So I suppose I have to setup a route inside my `info.module.ts`. It looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: InfoPage,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'item',
    component: ItemInfoPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ItemInfoPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [InfoPage, ]
})
export class InfoPageModule {}
```

With the url `http://localhost:8101/tabs/(info:info)` I get to my info tab page and I thought with `http://localhost:8101/tabs/(info:info)/item` I would go to my item-info page. However I just get redirected back to `http://localhost:8101/tabs/(info:info)`.

This is my `tabs.router.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        outlet: 'home',
        component: HomePage
      },
      {
        path: 'info',
        outlet: 'info',
        component: InfoPage
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        outlet: 'about',
        component: AboutPage
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        outlet: 'contact',
        component: ContactPage
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

And here is my `tabs.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    TabsPageRoutingModule,
    HomePageModule,
    AboutPageModule,
    ContactPageModule,
    InfoPageModule,
    ItemInfoPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

Also here is another question: Why do I have to use the route `tabs/(info:info)` and why does `tabs/info` not work? I specified the path to be `info` so why does it not work like this?

EDIT:

2nd way that might work but doesn't for me:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        outlet: 'home',
        component: HomePage
      },
      {
        path: 'info',
        outlet: 'info',
        component: InfoPage,
        children: [
          { path: 'item', outlet: 'info', component: ItemInfoPage}
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        outlet: 'about',
        component: AboutPage
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        outlet: 'contact',
        component: ContactPage
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every child route should be placed under children property. In your case you declared that route for info page is `/tabs/info` and when you try to access path `/tabs/yourVariable/info` you got redirected, because such path doesn't exist. And `tabs/info` is a static path while `/tabs/:info` is a dynamic path. Difference that second is not at info url but at for example `/tabs/iaminsanevariable`, where router parameter info = iaminsanevariable.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',     
    children: [
      {
        path: ':home',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
         { path: 'info',
           outlet: 'info',
           component: InfoPage }
        ]
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
 ...
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if I understand what your saying. I have added the tabs router in my post like you have here. But I still can't go to `http://localhost:8100/tabs/(info:info)/item`

Comment: what you did a static route for `/tabs/info/item` and it looks like you want to use info as a parameter and to use info as parameter you need to modify it like: `path: ':info'`. https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter

Comment: No I don't want to use a parameter. I'm currently just trying to go one page deeper.

Comment: Did you add <router-outlet> in your templates in info and tabs components?

Comment: router outlets are automatically created when you are using the tabs template.